# Regular expression to select the first digit after a word

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have a text like

```
number1234567890
```

I wanted to select the first digit after a word in this case it would result to `1`.

So far, I got a result of `r1` using a `(\D)(\d)` regex.

Hoping someone could help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the programming language?

Comment: If you are using a language such as Java or C#, then there is a nice string splitting option.  You may split on the lookaround `(?<=\D)(?=\d)`.  Then, check the second string, if it exists, and take the first letter.  If there is no second string, then your text has no numbers.

Comment: Use `(?<=\D)\d`. Or `^\D*\K\d` (PCRE) or `(?<=^\D*)\d` (.NET). Besides, you may just use `\d` if you can perform a *single* match operation (like `str.match(/\d/)` in JS, `preg_match('~\d~', $s, $match)` in PHP, etc.)

Comment: sorry guys for not mentioning the specific language, actually I use it for ansible, did not know that there are differences and I guess that is why I did not get the correct result, I use JS before from [link](https://regexr.com). I tried all the suggestions and Wiktor answer `(?<=\D)\d`  or `^\D\K\d`  got it correct

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew would you able to answer it officially so that I could mark it as an answer. Thanks for all the suggestion much appreciated.

Comment: What exactly worked for you? I added many alternatives.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `(?<=\D)\d` and `^\D\K\d` (PCRE) works for me.

Comment: I posted with explanations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<=\D)\d
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hfl9AG/1).

The `(?<=\D)` is a positive lookbehind that requires a character other than a digit to appear immediately to the left of the current location and then `\d` will match a digit that appears immediately to the right.

Or, a PCRE only variation:

```
^\D*\K\d
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hfl9AG/2).

It will match the start of the string, then any 0+ chars other than digit, then `\K` will reset the match buffer removing all the text matched so far, and `\d` will match the (first) digit.